# why cant I get this if statement to show?

Tags: python, if-statement

so I need to make sure the information I am inputting shows if its less than, greater than, or equal too.
not sure if the variable is messed up or not.
here is the code:

```
#the main function
def main():
    print   #prints a blank line
    age = getAge ()
    weight = getWeight()
    birthMonth = getMonth()
    print
    correctAnswers(age, weight, birthMonth)

#this function will input the age
def getAge():
    age = input('Enter your guess for age: ')
    return age

#thisfunction will input the weight
def getWeight():
    weight = input('Enter your guess for weight: ')
    return weight

#thisfunction will input the age
def getMonth():
    birthMonth = raw_input('Enter your guess for birth month: ')
    return birthMonth

#this function will determine if the values entered are correct
def correctAnswers(age, weight, birthMonth):
    if age <= 25:
        print 'Congratulations, the age is 25 or less.'

    if weight >= 128:
        print 'Congatulations, the weight is 128 or more.'

    if birthMonth == 'April':
        print 'Congratulations, the birth month is April.'

#calls main
main()
```

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited your code so that it will work correctly.

```
def main():
    print   #prints a blank line
    age = getAge()
    weight = getWeight()
    birthMonth = getMonth()
    print()
    correctAnswers(age, weight, birthMonth)

#this function will input the age
def getAge():
    age = input('Enter your guess for age: ')
    return age

#thisfunction will input the weight
def getWeight():
    weight = input('Enter your guess for weight: ')
    return weight

#thisfunction will input the age
def getMonth():
    birthMonth = raw_input('Enter your guess for birth month: ')
    return birthMonth

#this function will determine if the values entered are correct
def correctAnswers(age, weight, birthMonth):
    if int(age) <= 25:
        print('Congratulations, the age is 25 or less.')

    if int(weight) >= 128:
        print('Congatulations, the weight is 128 or more.')

    if birthMonth == 'April':
        print('Congratulations, the birth month is April.')

#calls main
main()
```

Comment: I see no indication that they are actually trying to use Python 3.

Comment: Yep, i have edited my answer to reflect  your suggestion.

Comment: this version is 3.8.1

Comment: If you are using python 3+ interpreter then it is not possible to use print statements without parentheses. And you have to use `input` in place of `raw_input` function

Comment: I added the parentheses after I posted the question

Comment: thank you! I was comparing the updated program to mine and I saw the problem.

Comment: you're welcome, if that answers your question you can accept it as correct answer to mark the question as completed.

Answer (score 1):

`input()` function returns a string. Before performing the integer comparison you are trying to do, you have to convert string.

For example:

```
def getAge():
    age = input('Enter your guess for age: ')
    return int(age)
```